# Is there any way how to make Windows 2012 Server close connection with high ping?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

As title says.
Is there any way how to make Windows 2012 Server close connection with high ping?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not the database server's job. It's the job of your firewall.

Comment: Ok thanks I use it as application server I just thought that there are maybe some tools to control this.